# @media not working for iphone 5

Tags: css

i'm using an emulator currently at http://mobiletest.me/ but my site is all over the place. The media code i'm using is this:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
```

but it isn't seeming to use this media query and is using my other query for ipad with is `@media (max-width:768px)`

I am using this meta in my html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I have the media queries in descending order `1600px 1280px 768px` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use :

```
@media only screen and (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 568px){}
```

Answer (score 0):

`device-width` refers to the actual width of the device someone's using, not the viewport width.

In your example:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px)
```

Could target iPhone 4's 'portrait' view (640px).

This is important because the iPhone 4 (and many other mobile devices for that matter) for example crams in 2 pixels per 'CSS' pixel. This means the device-width of the iPhone 4 is 320px / 480px, whereas the viewport width is actually 640px / 960px.